# Is there an open source implementation of Mathematica-the-language?

Tags: programming, open-source

I've seen questions before such as "[What is the best open-source equivalent for Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550/best-open-source-mathematica-equivalent)", but that specific question (and that line of inquiry in general) cares more about the computer algebra system and less about the core language and its unique and powerful features.

My interest in Mathematica come from a slightly different angle--namely, I find a tremendous amount of value in the power and flexibility of the *language* that Mathematica implements (I think of it as a slightly less scary looking syntax for Lisp with some very novel additions such as the powerful pattern matching system).

**Are there any projects that have made a concerted effort to build a Mathematica-the-language work-alike instead of focusing on the Computer Algebra System?**

[Mathics](http://mathics.github.io/) is the closest project I've found so far (since it does, in fact, try to stay faithful to Mathematica syntax where it can), but even it pitches itself as a computer algebra system. And it was written in Python, which isn't bad by itself, but it sets itself up to not be as fast as Mathematica for computationally intensive tasks.

It seems to me that Wolfram Research would actually benefit tremendously from having an even bigger programmer community around Mathematica as a language and developer platform, because more packages would be produced to solve more off-the-shelf programming problems (just like almost any other programming language).

An open (or at least freely available) implementation of the core programming language wouldn't even dilute their secret sauce which I would say primarily lies in Mathematica's base of mathematical rules and algorithms, in the scientific computing tools that they've bundled into one enormous and broad package, and into the insanely well-integrated notebook experience that they should have no trouble keeping ahead of any kind of open source project.

Comment: "Nope" is perhaps too short an answer for such a long question. But nonetheless is true.

Comment: It feels almost like flamebait on this site, but it's worth mentioning anyways, at the very least for future googlers:  you may also want to look into [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), the open-source equivalent to Matlab's language.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The question was asked specifically about Mathematica, which is sufficiently different from Matlab to make your comment of no relevance here, particularly given the context of the question.

Comment: @sblom, you may find [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/qisot/im_stephen_wolfram_mathematica_nks_wolframalpha/) interesting. In the first few paragraphs Stephen talks about a more freely available pure language aspect of Mathematica.

Comment: Why would you even want such a thing to exist? It would be like distributing a counterfit pharmaceutical, when the real one is available inexpensively available for experimentation.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe, I think it's more like a generic than a counterfeit. And inexpensive or not, the price tag even for the Home Edition (which I own) is high enough to disqualify Mathematica from participation in programming competitions like [Google Code Jam](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6389/178). I really want to see a day where Mathematica has as rich of an ecosystem of shared packages as MATLAB has, and I believe that a free clone is very possibly part of the equation.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: OP / @user21, just wanted to add a permalink to that post (as it is, indeed, interesting): https://reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/qisot/im_stephen_wolfram_mathematica_nks_wolframalpha/c3xz8by?context=1#thing_t1_c3xxgx3

Comment: Exactly what is meant by "Mathematica-the-language"? Just what the Documentation Center includes under "Core Language & Structure"? If so, that would exclude string manipulation and graphics, among other things.

Comment: Pattern-matching, replacement rules, "conditional term rewriting," are the core features that set Mathematica apart (and 'above' IMO) from almost everything else on the planet (ok, there is Maude and maybe parts of Coq, but not much else). These features have nothing to do with syntax, with the libraries of solvers, with applications. Thankfully, they finally gave a name to the language itself ("Wolfram") so we can stop confusing the language with the applications. It's classic "form versus content," with Wolfram's being the form and Mathematica's being the content.

Comment: this is my attempt to mimic Mathematica syntax with C++ https://gitlab.com/yoshiF7d/math

Comment: While not "open source", it is perhaps worth mentioning here that Mathematica is available for Raspberry Pi computers (bundled with NOOBS) and is free for noncommercial use. [https://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/](https://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/)

Comment: The answer is no longer "nope". Mathics is it.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I've been collecting these links for a while, so this question is a good excuse for a link dump. I'm not sure which project is the "best", but I think that *mathics* and *symja* are two of the more active and developed projects.

**Lisp:**
[MockMMA](https://github.com/dubrousky/mockmma) is probably the first implementation of the Mathematica language. It was written by [Richard Fateman](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/) who had a bit of a [scuffle with Wolfram Research](https://web.archive.org/web/20110809124303/http://www.math.utexas.edu/pipermail/maxima/2002/003246.html) over the code.

**Python:**
[Mathics](https://mathics.github.io/) (which you mentioned in the question) is primarily a syntax layer ontop of sympy and sage, not an independent implementation of the Mathematica language.
[Pythonica](https://github.com/mikexstudios/pythonica) is an abandoned python implementation of Mathematica.

**Java:**
[symja](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) is a pure Java library for symbolic mathematics that uses Mathematica notation and supports [Rubi Integration rules](https://rulebasedintegration.org/).
[omath](https://github.com/omath/omath) is an project that is still under development that will have a Mathematica like syntax, but does not aim to blindly copy Mathematica.

**Go:**

[expreduce](https://github.com/corywalker/expreduce) an experimental computer algebra system written in Go.

---

The *omath* page also has some interesting links to papers describing some of the Mathematica language's algorithms:
[Matching in flat theories](http://www.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_131/Kutsia-UNIF03.pdf) by Temur Kutsia.
A detailed description of Mathematica's flat pattern matching. (But quite technical!) (original link)

[Mathematica as a Rewrite Language](http://www.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_342/1996-11-01-A.pdf) by [Bruno Buchberger](http://www.risc.jku.at/people/buchberg).

[On the implementation of a rule-based programming system and some of its applications](http://www.risc.jku.at/people/tkutsia/papers/Kutsia-Marin-WIL.pdf) by Mircea Marin and Temur Kutsia.
These people obviously understand Mathematica's pattern matching enumeration system forwards and backwards.

Discussions about whether computer languages can be copyrighted, [1](http://www.math.utexas.edu/pipermail/maxima/2002/003246.html), [2](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math.symbolic/browse_frm/thread/69f1c7a17566d2ac/745c3dcbc9cce05f#745c3dcbc9cce05f), [3](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.misc/browse_frm/thread/ff8cb7602fcafa40).

Comment: Fixed the broken links - the [RISC site](http://www.risc.jku.at/) is really handy for references! Some good packages (some of which [I've played with](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66442/)) and notes are also on that site.

Comment: you might be interested in Roman Maeder's papers on [AlgBench](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/indices/a-tree/m/Maeder:Roman.html).

Comment: Now what is the best supported?  It doesn't really say that in the answer.  Better yet do you mind posting some examples?

Comment: @Liam: Mathics and Symja are still active - but I don't know about best supported. Both have the same syntax as Mathematica (although they have not implemented all of the Wolfram Language) - so there is no need to post examples. Both also have a online demo that you can try

Comment: should "understand Mathematica's pattern matching enumeration system backwards" be "[...] backwards **and forwards**"?

Answer (score 44):

Yes.

According to Mathematica's creator, Stephen Wolfram, Mathematica is just an implementation of a language that as of 2013 has been named [Wolfram](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2013/02/what-should-we-call-the-language-of-mathematica/)

Two other implementations have been developed by a Kernel Developer at Wolfram Research ([poeschko.com](http://www.poeschko.com/)).

One is called [Mathador](http://github.com/poeschko/Mathador), which is implemented in C++ and is no longer maintained, but the source may be of interest to you.

The other is called [Mathics](http://github.com/Mathics3/) and is currently (as of 2022) being maintained.  It is implemented in Python, uses the SymPy package to perform symbolic computations, and has a web browser interface.  You can check it out online at [mathics.org](http://mathics.org).

Comment: hi, just to make sure I understand, are you saying that the Wolfram Language  is/will be an  "open-source" implementation of language Mathematica?

Comment: @Nasser Switch "Wolfram language" and "Mathematica".

Comment: I am actually looking forward to seeing the Wolfram LRM (Language reference manual), which I assume will be published at some point in the future now that there is an official language called Wolfram.

Comment: @Nasser I don't think it is open source, in fact I don't really think that Mathics is 100% legal so it really isn't a cross compiler, but actually interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it's interesting to see that [WRI hired Jan Pöschko](http://www.poeschko.com/2012/12/new-challenges/) to [work on Wolfram Cloud](http://www.poeschko.com/2016/01/three-years-at-wolfram/) after he had written Mathics... makes sense!

Comment: If anyone needs help getting mathics installed, see https://github.com/Mathics3/mathics-django/issues/160

Answer (score 27):

### Expreduce

[Expreduce](https://github.com/corywalker/expreduce) is a new MIT-licensed project that has a fairly complete implementation of the language semantics. Further, it has a nice collection of definitions that provide CAS functionality, along with [documentation](https://corywalker.github.io/expreduce-docs/) to match. There is also a large testing suite for verification. It aims to have a small core with most of the functionality implemented in the language itself using the rewrite rule paradigm. The kernel is written in Go. Here are some examples of what can be computed:

```
In[1]:= D[Cos[Log[Sin[x]]+x]+x,x]

Out[1]= (1 + (-1 * (1 + Cot[x]) * Sin[(x + Log[Sin[x]])]))

In[2]:= Integrate[5*E^(3*x),{x,2,a}] // Expand

Out[2]= ((-5/3 * E^6) + (5/3 * E^(3 * a)))
```

The CAS functionality uses a collection of rewrite rules. For example, the product rule for derivatives is implemented using only one line:

```
D[a_*b_,x_] := D[a,x]*b + a*D[b,x]
```

The implementation is currently lacking in visualizations and the functionality of `Solve` among other things. Right now it is just a terminal, but perhaps there will be a Jupyter notebook interface for it in the future. It has virtually no dependencies. Since it does not call out to another open source CAS, there are many operations that it cannot do. Fortunately, the rule paradigm allows for fast development of new features. It could also benefit by getting the Risch algorithm for integration. Right now the integrations are mostly solved using heuristics.

### mmaclone

There is also an interesting Haskell implementation of the pattern matching engine by Yonghao Jin at https://github.com/jyh1/mmaclone.

Comment: I am wondering if it is capable of running [RUBI](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/).

Comment: I sent an email to Albert Rich to get his thoughts on this. It's an extremely impressive collection of rules, with a vast testing suite. I tried parsing one of the rule sets in Expreduce and it worked. I was even able to get some correct results returned. That said, there are many Q functions (some standard, some defined in the utils source) in his conditionals that Expreduce does not support. I would say that the pattern matching is there, but it would need some more built in functions. I think support for this collection should drive v0.3 development. Pull requests welcome :P.

Comment: Expreduce supports rubi